# Disregarding the claim of perpetual motion. Does this design have any merit at all?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, perpetual-motion

I'm wondering, in reference to this [youtube video](http://youtu.be/WQEbXD4Kqwc)

Whether or not this design would actually make the wheel move. Any big brains out there wanting to help me out would be greatly appreciated [image]

Comment: "Disregarding the claim of perpetual motion" means that you expect people here to disregard physics in general, as the concept of perpetual motion is a pillar concept in physics. If you dont expect an answer based on physics, why would you even bother to ask here?

Comment: @qftishard Luke is not asking us to ignore conservation of momentum: he's asking us to explain the working of the device in the video without necessarily addressing the obvious thermodynamic falsehood that it is a "perpetual motion device." For the device to work as claimed, we would have to disregard laws of thermodynamics, which are also pillars of physics.

Comment: Also the force does act radially

Comment: The claim that the force is tangential is false. Only if weight L is spinning, is there a tangential force, but then it's nothing special, just a pair of gears, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

The weight L needs to do work on Y to move the cart and therefore must itself move. The cart won't move at all if L is held rigid; otherwise it will be briefly accelerated while L falls.

Answer (score 1):

No.  It will only move if `L` is started spinning initially, or perhaps very slightly if `L` is dropped.  Note that in the video, he starts it spinning before it moves, and at the end, once he stops the spinning motion and sets it down - it doesn't start moving again.

That's also why springs are necessary to pull `L` towards `Y` (or the other wheel) -- so that the rotation can be transferred effectively.

Aside: the comment on the video *"The bike doesn't move while directed to Earth poles. This phenomenon is not explained yet. I'm working on it."* should be a red flag...

Answer (score 1):

First notice that all forces are internal, so by the third newton law the object's center of mass cannot move. More explicitly. The horizontal component of the force on Y will create a reactive force on L in the opposite direction. This force will transfer through the red bar and push the green part to the right. The force over Y by the green bar will be equal in magnitude and opposite to that of Y, so the net motion will be zero. My opinion is that the video is fake.